# Right kind of statistical analysis?

Tags: model-selection

I'm performing a user study where we are attempting to compare two forms of measurement of participant state-of-mind. Both measurements are numerical scores - one is self-reported, and the other is generated by an algorithm - they can both be put in a scale of 0-1. These scores are reported to test multiple states of mind (i.e. drowsiness, happiness, etc.).

We had participants watch movies designed to generate various states, and are interested in comparing the results of the measurements with each other. The issue is that not all participants watched the same movies (of 10 total movies, participants watched a random selection of 6).

Thus, we have data of the same scale for two different forms of measurement for a variety of movies watched.

I've been trying to determine (if there is) a statistically valid method to compare the measurements, given that the videos are different for the participants.

I'm guessing I could do a simple regression between the two forms of measurement, but am not sure if this is correct. Any thoughts? Many thanks.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that they could be placed on a 0-1 scale, what was the actual scaling used by participants?  Are there relationships between scales?  For example, drowsiness probably is mutually exclusive with extreme excitement.  How many scales did they rate on?  Is the algorithm from physical measurements or something else?

Comment: Participants reported in a likert-scale format (1-7) for each of the various qualities (happiness, anger, etc.). The algorithm determines emotion from camera recordings.

Comment: PS: For clarity, the algorithm outputs values from 0-1 for each of the various qualities (same labels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, the self-rating is ordinal.  There is no reason that your 1 and my 1 should represent the same stimulus, whether internal or external.  The second variable is at least ordinal but may represent physical data that is ratio data.

In that case, you are comparing relative rankings to relative rankings.  It isn't problematic that you did not give the same film to each participant unless it creates other validation issues.  Star Wars, the Color Purple, Operation Petticoat, and 12 Angry Men are quite different as films go.  Had you created a metric that worked perfectly when watching Gone With The Wind and no other film, it wouldn't be very valuable.

Your first task would be to plot any raw data to be sure that the relationship is monotone.  For example, if the self-report values increase then the machine-created values increase consistently, or decrease consistently.  What you are hoping to avoid is something like a parabola or some other inconsistently changing curve.  It does not matter if it is non-linear because you are working with ranks, but any simple rank correlation measure is going to assume monotonicity.  If x goes up, then y consistently goes up, consistently goes down, or consistently goes sideways.

You cannot run a regression because your values are relative values based on the internal ranking system of each person.  It is a reflection of their personal utility function and their rewards in the system.  The values are not really numbers.

The two primary choices for measures of correlation are Spearman's $\rho$ and Kendall's $\tau$.  When sample sizes are large their performance tends to be similar.  With small sample sizes, particularly if you have many tied values which will happen with a Likert-type scale, then Kendall's $\tau$ performs better because it can account for tied values whereas Spearman's $\rho$ does not.

You would leave your data in its raw form, there is no reason to transform it.

As long as your data is monotone, Kendall's $\tau$ would test whether or not no relationship existed between the variables assuming you used the standard *no effect* hypothesis from RA Fisher, or, $\tau=0$ as your null hypothesis.

If Kendall's $\tau$ were positive, it would imply that if the self-reported value increases then the machine value increases, but not necessarily in a linear manner.  If Kendall's $\tau$ were negative, then it would imply that as the self-reported value increased, the machine-created value would decrease.

You can find information on monotonic functions [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function)  I have attached the link in the event you have not thought about them before.

If you could not reject the null that $\tau=0$, then you can say the scores are not associated.

I cannot answer validity issues here as you didn't provide enough information and it really is a very different can of worms.  The measurement issue, however, should tend to favor Kendall's $\tau$ since you may have many tied observations.

Both Kendall's $\tau$ and Spearman's $\rho$ tend to be biased measures with small samples, but there is nothing much you can do to avoid that except to make sure that you have a lot of data.

If you are testing many relationships, such as happiness, anger, fear, etc..., then you will also need to make corrections for multiple comparisons.

It is important to understand that you are not mapping one set of values onto another set of values as you would in a regression.  Ordinal rankings lose information so that the only value a graph holds is to check to verify that the relationship is monotone.  Had you used the letters A for totally disagree and G for totally agree with the standard letter ordering instead of a numerical 7-point scale, it would have made no difference at all to the calculation of Kendall's $\tau$ other than to make it inconvenient to perform.

Comment: Lots of good thoughts here, although I suspect that it is of more interest to make statements about how strong the relationship is rather than testing whether it is nonzero (if the measurements are constructed in a more or less insightful way, it should certainly be nonzero, but that's not enough to say that they are "well enough" related, whatever that means in this situation). A graph can give also a good impression about the strength of relationship, adding to the plain value of Kendall's $\tau$.

Comment: @Dave, this makes perfect sense. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Lewian I absolutely agree.  However, the question was about the correct test and not about the validity or scientific meaningfulness.  Indeed, I am the wrong person to ask about the meaningfulness of a relationship for this topic.  I once tested 78 models of bankruptcy.  All were "significant," but only two were meaningfully useful.  The combined posterior probability of seventy-six models was less than 1/10,000 of one percent.  That assumes there were no significant digit issues.  Also, one can set the null at any point if one would decide what "well enough" meant.

Comment: @Lewian there is a danger, in practice, that one is happy that their result is statistically significant instead of scientifically meaningful.  The two tend to be conflated.

Comment: @DaveHarris "However, the question was about the correct test " - As far as I can see, the original question doesn't ask for a test, rather for any method. (I'm mentioning it because I think that we tend to think "test" too quickly, too automatically, in too many situations.)

Comment: @Lewian, yes, I agree with you.